# Disable and Enable drop-down list in form-Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I wanted to disable a dropdown while adding a new item in Sharepoint Online List.
I used the following code and it **worked**.

```
$("select[Title='Status']").prop("disabled", "disabled");
```

Now I want to use If-Else condition
So when the condition matches i.e. on "if" the drop-down should be disabled
Otherwise i.e. the drop-down should be enabled(editable)

Comment: Whats the condition you want ?

Comment: @KarthikJaganathan
there is a drop down list which has values from 0-4, if you select 0,1 or 2 the field should be disabled or else if u select 3 or 4 it should be enabled back, the which I want to disable/enable is also a drop-drown list

Comment: whats the name of dropdown which has values from 0-4 ??

Comment: @KarthikJaganathan   'level'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below code,

```
$("select[title*='level']").change(function() {
    if($('option:selected', this).text()=== "0" || $('option:selected', this).text() === "1" || $('option:selected', this).text() === "2"){
        $("select[Title*='Status']").prop("disabled", true);
    }           
    else{
        $("select[Title*='Status']").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

1. If you select 0 or 1 or 2 in the "Level" dropdown then the "Status" dropdown will be disabled.
2. If you select 3 or 4 in the "Level" dropdown then the "Status" dropdown will be enabled.

Comment: @KarthikJaganthan thanks, it worked

Comment: @VikasPandey Kindly upvote and mark it as answer, so that it will be helpful for others too in future